# Elasticsearch query on data with multi level child

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

Given this sample data:

```
"users": {
    "user1": {
         "first": "john",
         "last": "bellamy"
     },
    "user2": {
         .....
         .....
     }
 }
```

How can I set up elasticsearch to query/search on child **`first`** and **`last`**? Ohter tutorials only shows one level child, not this 2 or more level child.

I tried looking for a solution, and I guess that it has something to do with `mapping` option?

I just started elasticsearch few days ago, already manage to set up and adding data.

Comment: users is not a nested_type or key hash?

Comment: @user3775217 I don't think so, cause the `users` is not an array..

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "term": {
                    "users.user2.firstname": {
                        "value": "sumit"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

**nested users approach**

mappings

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "test_type": {
            "properties": {
                "users": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "firstname": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "lastname": {
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "nested": {
                    "inner_hits": {},
                    "path": "users",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{
                                "term": {
                                    "users.firstname": {
                                        "value": "ajay"
                                    }
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue here is `user1`, `user2` (aka userId) is the one I want to return, I want to use it like this:


`find user with first name john` -> then reutrn the userId

Comment: since user1 and user2 are users you can make users as nested object  and you can then use nested innerhits